# Matching data from 3 different data frames

Tags: r, dataframe, match

I have 3 data frames as follows:

```
d1 <- data.frame(level1 =  c("A", "A", "B", "C", "C"), 
             level2 = c("AA", "AB", "BA", "CA", "CB"))

d2 <- data.frame(level1 =  c("A", "A", "A","B", "B", "C", "C"), 
             level3 = c("1", "2", "4", "2", "3", "1", "5"))

d3<- data.frame(level3 = c("1", "2", "3", "4", "5"), AA = c("v1", "v2", "v3", "v4", "v5"), 
            AB = c("v6", "v7", "v8", "v9", "v10"), BA = c("v11", "v12", "v13", "v14", "v15"), 
            CA = c("v16", "v17", "v18", "v19", "v20"),  CB = c("v21", "v22", "v23", "v24", "v25"))
```

I would like the have as output these 3 data frames:

```
A <- data.frame(level3 = c("1", "2", "4"), AA = c("v1", "v2", "v4"), AB = c("v6", "v7", "v9"))

B <- data.frame(level3 = c( "2", "3"), BA = c("v12", "v13"))

C <- data.frame(level3 = c("1", "5"), CA = c("v16", "v20"), CB = c("v21", "25"))
```

From the provided 3 dataframes (d1 , d2 and d3), I would like to obatin a separate dataframe for every "Level1" (A, B, C..).

These output dataframes should contain the columns following the d1 criteria. The rows should contain the level3 numbers that match following the criteria of d2.

For example,

As per d1, AA and AB match with A. So data frame A should contain these 2 columns.

As per d2, 1,2,4 match with A, so these should be the rows in the data frame "A".

The values of data frame "A" should be based on d3. I hope I explained myself. Thanks,

.

Any ideas of how this could be done?

In my real example Level1 and Level2 nomenclatures have nothing in common.

Thanks for your support,

Comment: What are you doing here?Could you please explain a bit?

Comment: From the provided 3 dataframes (d1 , d2 and d3), I would like to obatin a separate dataframe for every "Level1" (A, B, C..). 

These output dataframes should contain the columns following the d1 criteria. The rows should contain the level3 numbers that match following the criteria of d2.

 For example, 

As per d1, AA and AB match with A. So data frame A should contain these 2 columns. 

As per d2, 1,2,4 match with A, so these should be the rows in the data frame "A". 

The values of data frame "A" should be based on d3. 

I hope I explained myself. Thanks,

Comment: As per d1, AA and AB match with A? Can you explain what is "A" is here?

Comment: For example: Level 1: A, B, C could be States in the US Say A= Texas Level 2: AA, AB, could be cities .e.g. AA= Austin, AB= San Antonio Level 3: 1, 2, 3.. could be occupations e.g. 1=Doctor, 2=Lawyer, 3= Engineer The values v1, v2, v3 could be salaries. So I would like to have an output such that I have a separate dataframe per state, with columns that have cities corresponding to each state. And the observations indicate the salary per occupation. I hope this helps. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

Using `reshape2` `melt` and `dcast` and `merge` and `split`

```
library(reshape2)
# merge three data sets together (putting d3 in long form)
full <- merge(merge(d1,d2),melt(d3, id = 1, variable.name = 'level2'))
results <- lapply(split(full, full$level1, dcast, formula =level3~level2, value.var = 'value')

# the results are in a list, we can copy to the global environment using `list2env`
# if you want (but you may wish to stay as a list
list2env(results, .GlobalEnv)
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, when trying to apply it I get the following error when generating the "results" variable:

Error in is.function(FUN) : 'FUN' is missing

Answer (score 0):

This is a bit clumsy but I think it does what you want:

```
# put d1 and d2 in a single table
dm <- merge(d1, d2)

# divide in individual dataframes based on level1 value
dspl <- split(dm, dm$level1)

# identify unique values for each level1 value
int1 <- lapply(dspl, apply, 2, unique)

# create a new dataframe:
int2 <- lapply(int1, function(x) d3[x[[3]],c("level3",x[[2]])]) 

# get the names of the level1 value to assign to objects
ndf <- names(int2)

# assign each dataframe to an object in the global environment
dmm <- lapply(ndf, function(lab) assign(lab, int2[[lab]], .GlobalEnv))
```